# Why do ints and dicts behave differently in nested functions?

Tags: python, nested-function

This is my code:

```
def outer():
    x = 0
    d = { 'a' : 'b' }
    def inner():
        for _ in xrange(10):
            x += 1
            d['a'] = x
            yield x
    for y in inner():
        print y
    print "%d rounds" % (x)

outer()
```

Which gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 14, in <module>
    outer()
  File "xxx.py", line 11, in outer
    for y in inner():
  File "xxx.py", line 8, in inner
    x += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

If I define `x` locally in `inner` the problem disappears. In other words: `inner` can not modify the externally defined integer, but it can modify the dictionary. I guess this is because assigning `x` requires read/write access to it, but assigning to the dictionary does not require read/write access to the dictionary: the update is done to an *element* of the dictionary?

How can I implement `inner` so that I can access **and** modify the variable `x` defined `outer`?

Comment: You are **rebinding** `x` to a new value. `x += 1` for an immutable `x` *has* to bind `x` to a new value. `x += something` for a mutable value will still rebind, but can *potentially* change the mutable object in place. `d['a'] = x` doesn't rebind the name `d` to anything else, it mutates the object *referenced* by `d`. `d` still points to the dictionary, only `d['a']` is altered to add a new key or update an existing key to reference whatever `x` is referencing.